# Web.config maxRequestLength ignored, only maxAllowedContentLength works

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, web-config, com-interop, iis-8

I've searched for a while, but can't seem to find anything that deals with the specific situation I'm facing.

I've set maxRequestLength to 5MB like so...

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="5120"/>
```

and then I've set maxAllowedContentLength to 20MB...

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="20971520"/>
```

For some reason though the lower limit is ignored. My application is allowing files up to 20MB to be uploaded.

It thought anything over maxRequestLength should trigger a .Net exception.

The application is classic ASP, with a custom Interop COM object managing the upload.

If I upload directly with .Net, the limits are respected, and the exceptions are thrown.

Does anyone know why maxRequestLength is ignored for ASP and/or COM?

This is happening in IIS 8 and IIS 10.

I have the following set, if it makes a difference...

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know why maxRequestLength is ignored for ASP and/or COM?

As well as all the other `system.web` settings, it is an ASP.NET setting. You already have experienced. So it's normal to be ignored for non ASP.NET requests.

From [httpRuntime Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Configures ASP.NET HTTP run-time settings that determine how to
>   process a request for an ASP.NET application.